# How to pass iterating json object in jquery to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In Ajax call populating data dynamically in html page.

**Requirement :** After populating if we click on button it should invoke JavaScript function along with required to pass object.
In JavaScript we need to access data using like value.id, value.title, value.description..... (Expected result)
But i am unable to fetch data from function argument, i tried with **stringify, parse** methods but didn't.

Please tell me, how can i access in JavaScript function?

```
success : function(data) {
 var listData = null;
 $.each(data.documentsList,function(index, value) { 
   //some logic ----------(iam able to get value.id, value.title, value.description...)
   listData += '<button value="Update" onclick="updateDocument(\''+ value + '\')">Update</button>'
   //some logic ----------
  });//each loop end
 $('#list').html(listData);
 },//success end

function updateDocument(document) {
    console.log("updateDocument" + document);  //[object object]
    console.log(document.title); //undefined
}
```

Comment: You should use event delegation using .on() for your dynamic buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not hooking up the event handler as a string but instead to the actual button object:

```
success : function(data) {
 $('#list').clear();
 $.each(data.documentsList,function(index, value) { 
   //some logic ----------(iam able to get value.id, value.title, value.description...)
   var button = $('<button type="button">Update</button>');
   button.on('click', function() {
       updateDocument(value);
   });
   $('#list').append(button);
   //some logic ----------
  });//each loop end
 },//success end

function updateDocument(document) {
    console.log("updateDocument" + document);  //[object object]
    console.log(document.title); //undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each dynamically added elements you should use `.on()` which binds events to dynamically added elements if matched with defined `selector`.

```
success : function(data) {

 $.each(data.documentsList,function(index, value) { 

   var button = $('<button type="button">Update</button>');
   button.on('click', function() {
       console.log("updateDocument" + value);
   });

   //append dynamically added element to list
   $('#list').append(button);

  });//each loop end
 },//success end
```

Answer (score 0):

First check that your function updateDocument() is reachable or not , you can place a normal console.log inside function and after that you can inspect that where is the actual point of problem . Also change the name of parameter from **document** to something else .

```
function updateDocument(res_doc) {
   console.log("updateDocument",  res_doc); // right way to print object 
   console.log("updateDocument " + res_doc); // wrong way to print object 
}
```

and if you are unable to call the function then you need to add event listener in different way to bind events to dynamically created element using **.on()** . You can check this link http://api.jquery.com/on/ for examles if required.